# getJSON problems

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have the following info in a file:

```
{"Morans Crossing":"Morans Crossing, NSW (2550)","Morangarell":"Morangarell, NSW (2666)"}
```

File name, for example, is `www.site.com/script.php`

I am calling it from `subdomain.site.com/script.js`

I am using the following JS:

```
function lookup(inputString) {
if(inputString.length == 0) {
    // Hide the suggestion box.
    $('#suggestions').hide();
} else {
$.getJSON("http://www.site.com/script.php",{queryString:inputString},function(data) {
      if(data.length > 0){
         var reply = "";
        $.each(data, function(key,val){
            reply += "<li onClick=\"fill('"+key+"');\">"+val+"</li>";
        });
        $('#suggestions').show();
        $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(reply);
     }
});
}
}
```

The JS is calling the info, and using firebug, I can see the params as what it should be on script.php, although the response and html are blank.

Any suggestions to get this working from subdomain.site.com?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible due to the [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). It is a security concept that only allows request to destinations with the same host as the origin. There is a workaround called `JSONP`. Here the client creates a new script tag to include JavaScript code from a foreign host, usually you pass a `callback` parameter so your code gets called. The server has to support `JSONP`.

---

**Working with Flickr**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=?",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(json) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Notice the `&jsoncallback=?` at the end of the url. That's the JSONP callback I was speaking about. The `?` signals jQuery that it can craft its own unique function identifier, which it maps to your `success` function.

Comment: Then how are flickr using getJSON for http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?